# How exactly does the MMU load a program from secondary memory to primary memory

Tags: operating-system

What exactly happens when I open an application or a program which is not cached in the main memory. 
a) How does the OS know where to look for the program?
b) If suppose all the pages cannot be loaded then does the address of the rest of the pages or at least starting address of the rest of the pages is maintained in the PCB?
c) Also is any information regarding the application is present in main memory, assuming it is never accessed before and it is not a critical component that has to be present in memory.

Any answers, follow-up questions, clarifications are welcome.

Edit: I have went through many links online but none states exactly what happens or who maintains the information. Most of the places it is stated that the program would be brought in the main memory by the page fault handler, I am looking for something more specific.

Comment: There are, like, millions of articles on paged memory-management on Google.

Comment: May be more, but none specifically state what happens, each one just says that "the page is brought in...", I was looking for something specific.

Answer (score 0):

Read about page tables and page faults. That's the mechanism behind it. If you want something very specific, download x86 CPU manuals from intel or AMD and read the chapters about the same.